# Can the hyperbolic plane be immersed in three dimensional Euclidean space, if we are only looking for a weak solution?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometric-immersion

Consider the following question:

"Can the hyperbolic plane $(\mathbb{R}^2, g_H)$ be isometrically 
immersed in three dimensional Eulidean space$(\mathbb{R}^3, g_{flat})$?"

I believe the answer to this question is no. Can someone give me a reference 
for this theorem (in particular I want to look at the details of the 
proof and understand why this is not possible).

My second question is as follows: I assume the answer is no if one is 
asking for smooth (i.e. $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$)  immersion. Is anything 
known if we relax this condition? More precisely, asking for an immersion 
is asking whether a certain pde has a solution. What happens if I am just 
looking for some "weak" solution to this pde?

Comment: This is known as Hilbert's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29 . If I recall correctly there is a discussion of this as well as other "no-go" theorems in the book "Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces" by Qing Han and Jia Xing Hong which you have cited in another question.  See also this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111101/surfaces-in-mathbb-r3-with-negative-curvature-bounded-away-from-zero

Comment: Thank you for the wikepedia reference. I do have the book you mentioned; I am not certain however if he discusses any notion of a "weak" solution for an immersion there.

Answer (score 18):

The [Nash-Kuiper embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) applies here, as the obvious smooth topological embedding of the hyperbolic plane as the unit disk in 3-dimensional Euclidean space decreases distances. Therefore there is a $C^1$ isometric embedding. I don't know of a stronger result.

Answer (score 10):

Without the deep theorem of Nash-Kuiper, it is easy to construct and visualize a
bi-Lipschitz embedding: think of those Dutch collars of the XVII century like this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rembrandt,_Portret_van_Haesje_v.Cleyburg_1634_2.jpg

Comment: See also http://hyperbolic-crochet.blogspot.com/2010/07/story-about-origins-of-model-of.html , which includes a picture of a paper model made by Beltrami.

Comment: @John Stillwell: Nice!

Answer (score 9):

Klotz Milnor proved in 1972 that there is no $C^2$ isometric embedding of $H^2$ in $R^3$ so Nash–Kuiper cannot be improved: [Zbl 0236.53055](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0236.53055).

A practical realisation of an embedding is here: [Crocheting the hyperbolic plane](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Edwh/papers/crochet/crochet.html) by David W. Henderson and Daina Taimina.

Comment: Note that the theorem is really due to Efimov (who proved that there is complete, $C^2$ surface in $R^3$ with curvature $K\leq -\epsilon<0$ -- this applies in particular to the hyperbolic plane). The paper by Klotz-Milnor is a (very nice) exposition of Efimov's result.

Comment: you mean of course there is NO such surface

Comment: Yes that's right of course! I don't see how to edit this comment now, but it should read "...that there is NO complete...". Thanks for the remark.