# About Pogorelov-Nadirashvili-Yuan's local isometric embedding counterexample

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Pogorelov's paper "An example of a two-dimensional Riemannian metric admitting no local realization in E3. Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR Tom 198(1), 42–43 (1971); English translation in Soviet Math. Dokl. 12, 729–730 (1971) 123" and Nadirashvili-Yuan's paper "Improving Pogorelov's isometric embedding counterexample. Calc. Var. Partial Differential Equations 32 (2008), no. 3, 319–323. 53C45", there is one local isometric embedding counterexample for $C^{2,1}$ Riemannian metric. As far as I know, those two papers are the only source for such counterexample for local isometric embedding.

There is a crucial estimate about graph's second derivatives: $\min_{-c\leq t_1\leq c} h_{11}(t_1, b)\leq (M- m)\frac{b^2}{c^2}$ (see page 322 of Nadirashvili-Yuan's paper). I can not verify this estimate.

Did anyone verify the above counterexample in details or know how to get the above estimate?

Comment: Related: See also my earlier question, [The geometry of Nadirashvili's complete, bounded, negative curvature surface](https://mathoverflow.net/q/52851/6094), and the two answers posted there.

Answer (score 2):

There is another paper, with a few more details:

JONATHAN HOLLAND: A TWO-DIMENSIONAL C 2,1 METRIC WITH NO LOCAL C2 EMBEDDINGIN R3, FOLLOWING POGORELOV

( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4166.pdf )

p.s. I am going through the details myself, so at the moment I can't answers your question directly.